# How to avoid null exception generated by EditorFor(x=x.Prop) in Create.cshtml when no instance of model class is passed to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

**Constraints:**

1. I don't want to use `Nullable` types.
2. I don't want to instantiate a model class in the `HttpGet`-handling `Create` action method.

**Model class:**

```
namespace MvcTest.Models
{
    public enum Gender { Male, Female }
    public class Person
    {
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Templated Editor Helper (Gender.cshtml):**

```
@using MvcTest.Models
@model Gender
@{
    var genders = from Gender g in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))
                  select new { Value = g, Text = g.ToString() };

    var sl = new SelectList(genders, "Value", "Text", Model);
}
@Html.DropDownList(string.Empty, sl, "--Select--")
```

**Controller:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcTest.Models;

namespace MvcTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            //Person p = new Person();
            //return View(p);

            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MvcTest.Models.Person
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Gender)
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

**Errors:**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'MvcTest.Models.Gender'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'MvcTest.Models.Gender'.

Source Error: 


Line 3:  {
Line 4:      
Line 5:      @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Gender)
Line 6:      <p>
Line 7:          <input type="submit" value="Create" />

Source File: e:\MvcTest\MvcTest\Views\Home\Create.cshtml    Line: 5 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'MvcTest.Models.Gender'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +143
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +377
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +584
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1027
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +118
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression) +57
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Create_cshtml.Execute() in e:\MvcTest\MvcTest\Views\Home\Create.cshtml:5
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +207
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +81
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +19
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +65
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +220
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +303
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8862381
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.225
```

**Question:**
How to avoid null exception generated by EditorFor(x=x.Prop) in Create.cshtml when no instance of model class is passed to the view?

Comment: Your second requirement is with an absolute contradiction with good practices and strongly typed views with view models.

Comment: @Darin: because I want the dropdown control to get populated with `--Select--` by default and not get populated with either `Male` or `Female`.

Comment: @Darin: I give up, I should use nullable enum :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you need to use nullable enums in order to achieve this. It would also make sense because when a value is not selected (`--SELECT--`) the enum must be null. Here's a [nice blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/05/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-dropdownlist-helper-for-enums.aspx) about useful extension methods.

Comment: @Darin: Are you sure the editor template will work for the `Edit` action method? I already tried it prior to ask this question. The drop down control will be `--Select--` in `Edit.cshtml`. The dropdown list control does not reflect the gender property.

Comment: @Administrator, you are correct. My initial answer won't work for the Edit action and it won't preselect the correct value in the dropdown list based on the model. The solution you found should work but I would stick with nullable enums as they would be semantically more correct for this scenario.

Comment: @Darin: Please see my update, I used your previous solution combined with @Branislav's `? : ` operator.

Comment: @Administrator, I saw your update and IMHO nullable enums would be better as you won't have to write all those conditions.

Comment: @Darin: When the model class is generated by Entity Data Model Wizard, how can you modify some properties to be nullable?

Comment: @Administrator in a properly architected ASP.NET MVC application you always should be using view models. Those are classes specifically tailored to the needs of a given view. So in your example that will be a class containing a nullable enum property as that's what the view requires. The controller will then query your repository to fetch a model (EF autogenerated classes) and map them to the corresponding view model and then pass this view model to the view. To ease this mapping you may take a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).