# Can we simplify the expression Model == null ? new SelectList(genders, "Value", "Text") : new SelectList(genders, "Value", "Text", Model);?

Tags: c#

```
Model == null ? 
new SelectList(genders, "Value", "Text") : 
new SelectList(genders, "Value", "Text", Model);
```

I want to avoid writing `new SelectList(genders, "Value", "Text"` twice, is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if you just use

```
new SelectList(genders, "Value", "Text", Model)
```

and let it pass in the null reference... is that fourth parameter definitely *meant* to be non-null?

EDIT: As an alternative, could you use a default value?

```
new SelectList(genders, "Value", "Text", Model ?? Genders.Male)
```

Comment: @Jon, it's a [long story](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402692/how-to-avoid-null-exception-generated-by-editorforx-x-prop-in-create-cshtml-whe) :-) That's why it's always better to provide context when asking questions. Obviously your answer makes perfect sense, had the OP followed my advice about nullable enums.

Comment: ...and could that constructor be augmentet to handle a `null` case separately?

Comment: @Jon: my question here related to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402692/how-to-avoid-null-exception-generated-by-editorforx-x-prop-in-create-cshtml-whe

Comment: @Jon, the problem is that Model is a non-nullable enum so he cant't use `Model ?? Genders.Male`.

Comment: @Darin: If Model is a non-nullable enum, then how can "Model == null" evaluate properly to start with?

Comment: @Jon, it can't, that's why unfortunately this question doesn't make much sense :-)

Comment: @Administrator: But what is the *type* of the `Model` expression?

Comment: @Jon: I made a mistake in the previous comment.

Comment: @Administrator: So what *is* the type of the `Model` expression? That's still a pretty crucial question...

Comment: @Jon: Yes, my question does not make sense. I use `Enum` :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything depend of the constructor, and there are a lot of possibilities to manage this here you go three options.

1: you may pass that Model when is null of course if this does not have some significant consequence.

2: Create object with `new SelectList(genders, "Value", "Text") :` and then set model using property.

3: Implement the [NullPatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for Model and use it when is null.